# C++ Using an enum data type as a data type for a constructor in a class file

Tags: c++, class, enums

I have this data type defined

```
 private:
    enum RankType {Rank2, Rank3, Rank4, Rank5, Rank6, Rank7, Rank8,
    Rank9, Rank10, RankJack, RankQueen, RankKing, RankAce };
```

and this constructor:

```
 public:
  RankType getRank();
```

but when I call it in the .cpp file like this:

```
RankType Card::getRank()
{
    return Card.RankType;
};
```

I get the error: "RankType does not name a type.

Comment: should `RankType` be an enum type, or a `Card` member variable? You can't make it both.

Comment: My bad, that was one of my attempts at fixing it. it should be 



**RankType Card::getRank()**

that is the line the error is on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make you notice that `RankType` is just the type (name) of the enum. You have created an `enum` inside your class, but you have no variable of type `RankType` (unless you are not showing us).

You are returning a type, what do you think `return Card.RankType;` means?

I recommend you to define the enum outside the class, and if you want to initialise your card to a certain RankType, you can do it, for example, when you create a new object, in the constructor.

This is where you define your class:

```
enum TypeRank {STRONG, WEAK};


class Card
{
private:
    TypeRank _type_rank = STRONG; // default initialisation

public:
    Card(TypeRank type_rank)
    {
        _type_rank = type_rank;
    }

    TypeRank get_rank()
    {
        return _type_rank;
    }
};
```

This is your main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Card.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Card card1(STRONG); // notice that the enum TypeRank is included
    // with the file 'Card.h'

    // prints 0, because STRONG is represented by the integer 0!
    std::cout << "This is the rank type: "<< card1.get_rank() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the whole code is here http://pastebin.com/YNmJ4auX i understand what you are saying, i just dont understand how i would fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Enumerations in pre C++11 are just a way of defining integer (constant) values. Your function should look like, for example,

```
RankType /* this is an integer, really */ Card::getRank()
{
    return Card::RankKing; // this is just syntactic sugar for an integer value 
}
```

The members of your `enum` are in a 1-to-1 correspondence with integer constants, in your case the enum starts from the default 0, so `Rank2` is 0, `Rank3` is 1 and so on.

You should create another variable that holds the `RankType` of your card, like `RankType rank_type;`, then initialize `rank_type` with the type you need at construction, then finally `Card::getRank()` should just return `rank_type`. Again, just think about the members of the `enum` as plain old numbers. Hope this is clear.